Tourette and autism: how common is the combination?
How common is a Tourette/autism combo? Wikipedia didn’t tell me how common the combination is.

Did you do an internet search? You'd be searching for comorbidity between Tourette's and autism. This site requires evidence of prior research (e.g. a quote and a link to the source) in an attempt to answer your question. Please edit your question to include the results and if there's something you don't understand, explain what you need to know. That's most likely to get you a useful response.

The co-occurrence of Tourette syndrome (TS) and autism spectrum disorder (ASD) is relatively common. Research indicates that there is a significant overlap between these two conditions:

Tourette Syndrome Prevalence in Autism: Studies have shown that between 6% and 21% of individuals with autism spectrum disorder also have Tourette syndrome or chronic tic disorder. This rate is significantly higher than in the general population, where TS affects approximately 0.3-0.8%.

Reference: Canitano R, Vivanti G. Tics and Tourette syndrome in autism spectrum disorders. Autism. 2007;11(1):19-28. doi:10.1177/1362361307070992

Autism Prevalence in Tourette Syndrome: Conversely, research suggests that up to 20-50% of individuals with Tourette syndrome may meet the diagnostic criteria for autism spectrum disorder.

Reference: Hirschtritt ME, Lee PC, Pauls DL, et al. Lifetime prevalence, age of risk, and genetic relationships of comorbid psychiatric disorders in Tourette syndrome. JAMA Psychiatry. 2015;72(4):325-333. doi:10.1001/jamapsychiatry.2014.2650
The reasons for this overlap are not entirely understood but may involve shared genetic and neurobiological factors. Both conditions are thought to arise from complex interactions between genetic and environmental influences affecting brain development and function.
